# Send Button in Contact Form is not Submitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, button, sendgrid

I am working on a contact form for my website where users can enter their name, email, and message, and the inquiry should be sent to the office's main email. I am using the SendGrid API to handle the email sending, and I have implemented the code for email handling in a file called server.js on the server side. However, when I press the send button, nothing seems to happen.

Here is my code for server.js (server-side code):

```
// server.js
const express = require("express");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const { resolve } = require("path-browserify");

// Set up SendGrid API key
sgMail.setApiKey("***********");

// Create Express app
const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON requests
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello, server!");
});

// Route to handle sending emails
app.post("/send-email", (req, res) => {
  const { Name, Email, Message, submitbutton } = req.body;

  const msg = {
    to: "******@gmail.com",
    from: "******@gmail.com",
    subject: "Example Subject",
    text: `Name: ${Name}\nEmail: ${Email}\nMessage: ${Message}\nSubmit Button: ${submitbutton}`,
    html: `<p>Name: ${Name}</p><p>Email: ${Email}</p><p>Message: ${Message}</p><p>Submit Button: ${submitbutton}</p>`,
  };

  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Email sent successfully" });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.toString());
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to send email" });
    });
});

// Set up fallback for path module
resolve.fallback = { path: require.resolve("path-browserify") };

// Start the server
app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

and here is my code for card.tsx (code for my form and client-side code):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import cardcss from "./Card.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

interface CardProps {
  imageUrl: string;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

function Card(props: CardProps) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const nameInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const emailInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const messageInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (messageInputRef.current) {
      messageInputRef.current.focus();
      messageInputRef.current.setSelectionRange(0, 0);

      // Delay setting the cursor position
      setTimeout(() => {
        messageInputRef.current?.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
      }, 0);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleFocus = (event: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.target.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  };

  const submitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (
      nameInputRef.current &&
      emailInputRef.current &&
      messageInputRef.current
    ) {
      const nameInput = nameInputRef.current.value;
      const emailInput = emailInputRef.current.value;
      const messageInput = messageInputRef.current.value;

      const contactData = {
        Name: nameInput,
        Email: emailInput,
        Message: messageInput,
      };

      axios
        .post("/send-email", contactData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          // Handle success response
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          // Handle error response
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    // JSX code for the contact form
    // ...
  );
}

export default Card;
```

I have ensured that the server.js file is running correctly, and the SendGrid API key is valid. However, when I press the send button on the form, nothing happens. On my form I even have "onSubmit: {submitHandler}" which should send the data to the server-side code...Can anyone help me identify the issue and why the form is not submitting and sending the email?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Hi, can you include how you have used the `submitHandler` function. Additionally you could add console.logs in multiple points of the function to see if it is being triggered in the first place and if the conditions you've mentioned are being adhered to.

Comment: do you mean the code for the submitHandler function or me explaining the logic behind it?

Comment: What happens if you put a console.log inside your submit handler? It would really be helpful if you posted the Form jsx code showing how your form is being submitted.

Comment: Hi I changed it as requested however I still receive this error in my console "xhr.js:210 POST localhost:3000/send-email 404 (Not Found)". I changed axios.post to "axios .post("localhost:3000/send-email", contactData) .then((response) => { console.log("Received email request"); // Handle success response }) .catch((error) => { console.error(error); // Handle error response }); }" and app.post in server.js to "app.post("/send-email", (req, res)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is running on port 4000. React probably runs on port 3000. Your axios.post seems to be going to /send-email on port 3000 and not to /send-email on port 4000.
If you change the axios.post to the full url (http://localhost:4000/send-email), it will probably work (if there isn't anything else giving a problem).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi I changed it as requested however I still receive this error in my console "xhr.js:210     POST http://localhost:3000/send-email 404 (Not Found)". I changed axios.post to "axios
        .post("http://localhost:3000/send-email", contactData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Received email request");
          // Handle success response
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          // Handle error response
        });
    }" and app.post in server.js to "app.post("/send-email", (req, res)"